# Cocoa: How to get textual representation for key equivalent like in menus?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmenuitem

I was wondering if there's a simple way of getting textual representation of key equivalents (that can be shown to user, like in menus)?
E.g.: suppose I have the key code (virtual or unichar, doesn't matter) and modifiers mask.
How do I convert these to NSString to get something like this: @"^M", or @"Ctrl+A"?

As long as menus have this functionality implemented, I suppose there must be some way of using it through Cocoa API? 
Or maybe there's some way to get those strings from NSMenuItem internals?